# How can I delete elements from a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I delete all the elements from an array, *except* for one in particular?

Comment: teh 1one1111onee, clearly @Ben :P

Comment: Wow. Loving the trigger-finger closing. That question is not a duplicate of this in any way at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unset individual elements using the `unset` function:

```
unset($array['element']);
```

A quick way to do what you intend is to simply create a new array:

```
$new_array = array('element' => $old_array['element']);
unset($old_array);
```

Or use array_slice:

```
$new_array = array_slice($old_array, $offset, 1, true);
```

Comment: your code is more clear (or usable at least) as `$myarray = array('element' => $myarray['element']);` great anwser!!!